# Converting an integer to Greek and Roman numerals

Tags: python, python-2.x, roman-numerals, number-systems

Yesterday I posted a question about [converting an integer to it's Roman Numeral equivalent](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/147712/convert-an-integer-to-its-roman-numeral-equivalent). Apparently you guys liked it and gave me some good advice, so I decided to take all your advice, and go a step further, it will now not only convert to Roman  but will now also convert to Greek numerals.

I would like some critique on this project that I'm continuing.

```
# <~~ coding=utf-8 ~~>
import argparse


opts = argparse.ArgumentParser()
opts.add_argument("-g", "--greek", type=int,
                  help="Convert to Medieval Numerals")
opts.add_argument("-r", "--roman", type=int,
                  help="Convert to Roman Numerals")
args = opts.parse_args()


ROMAN_NUMERAL_TABLE = (
    ("~M", 1000000), ("~D", 500000), ("~C", 100000),
    ("~L", 50000), ("~X", 10000), ("~V", 5000),  # "~" indicates a Macron
    ("M", 1000), ("CM", 900), ("D", 500),
    ("CD", 400), ("C", 100),  ("XC", 90),
    ("L", 50),   ("XL", 40),  ("X", 10),
    ("IX", 9),   ("V", 5),    ("IV", 4),
    ("I", 1)
)


GREEK_NUMERAL_TABLE = (
    ("α", 1), ("β", 2), ("γ", 3),
    ("δ", 4), ("ε", 5), ("Ϝ", 6),
    ("ζ", 7), ("η", 8), ("θ", 9),
    ("ι", 10), ("κ", 20), ("λ", 30),
    ("μ", 40), ("ν", 50), ("ξ", 60),
    ("ο", 70), ("π", 80), ("ϙ", 90),
    ("ρ", 100), ("σ", 200), ("τ", 300),
    ("υ", 400), ("φ", 500), ("χ", 600),
    ("ψ", 700), ("ω", 800), ("ϡ", 900),
    ("α", 1000), ("β", 2000), ("γ", 3000),
    ("δ", 4000), ("ε", 5000), ("ϛ", 6000),
    ("ζ", 7000), ("η", 8000), ("θ", 9000)  # The Greeks weren't very creative
)


def convert_init(number, convert_to=None):
    """ Convert a number to a numeral, Greek or Roman
    >>> print(convert_init(45, convert_to=GREEK_NUMERAL_TABLE))
    ϜϜϜϜϜϜϜγ
    >>> print(convert_init(45, convert_to=ROMAN_NUMERAL_TABLE))
    XLV """
    display_numerals = []

    for numeral, value in sorted(convert_to)[::-1]:  # sort the list from largest to least
        count = number // value
        number -= count * value
        display_numerals.append(numeral * count)

    return ''.join(display_numerals)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    if args.greek:
        data = convert_init(int(args.greek), convert_to=GREEK_NUMERAL_TABLE)
        with open("greek_numerals.txt", "a+") as file_data:
            file_data.write(data)  # Write it to a file

    elif args.roman:
        data = convert_init(int(args.roman), convert_to=ROMAN_NUMERAL_TABLE)
        with open("roman_numerals.txt", "a+") as file_data:
            file_data.write(data)

    else:
        raise NotImplementedError("{} is not implemented yet".format(args))
```

Key points I would like to focus on, of course critique the whole program.

1. I used writing to a file because when if I output it to the console I get an IO error, basically an encoding error. Does this have to do with my computer or with the program?
2. Would there be a way for me to condense the two `tuples` down into one and still convert correctly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your conversion routines make no sense.  I don't see why 45 should be `ϜϜϜϜϜϜϜγ`, as stated in your doctest.  I also get this clearly wrong result:

```
>>> convert_init(1939, ROMAN_NUMERAL_TABLE)
'XLXLXLXLXLXLXLXLXLXLXLXLXLXLXLXLXLXLXLXLXLXLXLXLXLXLXLXLXLXLXLXLXLXLXLXLXLXLXLXLXLXLXLXLXLXLXLXLXVIV'
```

Since you are using Unicode for the Greek numerals, I should be pedantic and point out that the [Roman numerals should also use the appropriate Unicode characters](//graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/49265/27140).

The docstring would be better written as

```
def convert_init(number, convert_to=None):
    """
    Convert a number to a Greek or Roman numeral

    >>> convert_init(45, convert_to=ROMAN_NUMERAL_TABLE)
    'XLV'
    """
    …
```

… since the `print` statement obscures the fact that you are returning a string.  (Based on just your docstring, it could also be returning some other kind of object, whose `__str__` produces the desired output.)

What is `convert_init`?  Did you mean `convert_int`?

Your `args = opts.parse_args()` is not guarded by `if __name__ == '__main__'` as it should be.  You shouldn't need to cast `int(args.greek)` or `int(args.roman)`, since `argparse` should take care of the `type=int` for you.

Comment: This should teach me to never assume that if someone posts here, the code actually works.

Comment: 1. @ChatterOne It does work. It just doesn't work as I assumed it would. 2. @200_success I got all the information for the Greek letters [here](http://www.russellcottrell.com/greek/utilities/greeknumberconverter.htm), are you telling me they're wrong? 3. Docstring is a valid critique, thank you. 4. Why does `argparse` have to be in the `if __name__ == '__main__'`? I don't see why that would really make a difference..?

Comment: @papasmurf If you say that your program doesn't work as you assumed it would, that's the same as saying there's a bug. So, no, it doesn't work. An example: the number 9 in roman numerals is `IX`, your output is `VIV`.

Comment: @ChatterOne Touche sir. Guess it's got some bugs in it lol. I'll fix them, thank you guys for bringing these to my attention

Answer (score 3):

- I wouldn't use `if __name__ == '__main__':` for extended logic. I'd put just a `main()` in there and do the checks/call the functions from there.
- Your script is supposed to have user input and output. Having an exception is a nice way to communicate between modules/functions, but with the user you may prefer a `print()`
- The behavior is not entirely consistent because launching the program with an unknown option triggers a message from `argparse` saying `unrecognized arguments` (which is correct). But if you launch it with no arguments you get the exception.
- You're checking using `if args.greek:` and `elif args.roman:`, but if you give a false value, they will fail. That means that passing `-r 0` on the command line will trigger the exception of not implemented. You should check against `None`, something like `if args.greek != None:`
- `convert_init` has a parameter `convert_to` with a default of `None`. Default values are supposed to be either valid or properly handled, and in this case `None` is ... well, none of the two.
- `convert_to` is not a proper name, because it suggests that there are two possible values, roman and greek, while in reality that's the lookup table you're going to use. I'd either rename it to `symbols_lookup` or (better IMO), keep the name and use it to determine which lookup table to use inside of the function.
- In `convert_init` you sort the values of `convert_to`, but they're static values, so you can sort them beforehand and use the values directly.
- You have a comment saying `# "~" indicates a Macron` which is useful. The other comments can (and should) go. You know that `file_data.write(data)` means `# Write it to a file`, no need to comment on that.